# How to pass data from directive to html template - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my directive:

```
angular.module('myPopUp',[])
.directive('myPopUp',['$document', function($document){

    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        controller: function($scope){
        },
        scope: {

        },
        templateUrl: 'popup.html',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr){
        var topPosition = top + (btnHeight/2) - (popOverHeight/2);

        }
```

After doing the calculation in link, how can I pass 'topPosition' to my popup.html template? Any ideas?

I try to do in this way, but it doesn't work.

popup.html:

```
<div class="popover right" style="width:auto;top:{{topPosition}}px;">
      <div class="arrow"></div>
      <div>.......</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I added $apply to my codes:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
var topPosition = top + (btnHeight/2) - (popOverHeight/2);
 scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.topPosition = topPosition;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign you variable to `scope`, like this

```
link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
    var topPosition = top + (btnHeight/2) - (popOverHeight/2);
    scope.topPosition = topPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope in contoller and scope in link are the same thing. Only difference is that $scope is injected via Dependency Injection whereas in `link fxn`scope is injected based on position. So for e.g.

```
link: function(element, scope, attr)
```

then `element` will still refer to scope.

so inside your `link` function you can assign `position` to scope like you will assign it in controller only difference is the variable name. E.g.

```
 .directive('myPopUp', function(){

        return{
            restrict: 'EA',
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.topPosition = 0; 
            },
            scope: {

            },
            templateUrl: 'popup.html',

            link: function(scope, elm, attr){
                scope.topPosition = 200; // calculate here as per your logic
            }}});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8ByG/115/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, however it still doesn't work. Am i missing anything? I have tried to add 
scope: {
topPosition: '@'
        },
but still not working....any ideas?

Comment: @user2991183 Updated and also included link to demo

Answer (score 0):

You can refer only scope variables in your template so your scope should have topPosition.

```
  link: function(scope, elm, attr){
            var topPosition = top + (btnHeight/2) - (popOverHeight/2);
            scope.topPosition = topPosition;  

    }
```